# what is the meaning of the value inside the vertex in dijkstra algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATqgU.jpg)
what is the meaning of the value inside the vertex in this graph.
I sholud solve it using dijkstra algorithm and to find the shortest path from vertex s to vertex z and then back from z to s.

It is not clear to me whether this is a value that needs to be calculated or not

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. It seems you have to apply Dijkstra algorithm on the graph. The value inside the vertex is the *vertex number*. It is useful in identifying the vertex.

Comment: The numbers are the calculated shortest path lengths from the root as you can see by the lengths of each edge.

Comment: *"It is not clear to me whether this is a value that needs to be calculated or not"*: it is to be calculated. (those are **not** vertex identification numbers, but shortest distances from vertex `s`)

Answer (score 0):

in Dijkstra's algorithm you calculate in a greedy way the shortest routes to all nodes. The value you are seeing here in every node is the shortest calculated path length to that specific node.